# I'm trying to open query.yahooapis.com but curl is trying to use IPV6 even if I only have IPV4 enabled

Tags: macos, ipv6, osx-yosemite, curl, ipv4

When I try to call query.yahooapis.com with curl it's trying to use the ipv6 address but IPV6 is disabled on my computer

```
$ curl -v 'http://query.yahooapis.com/'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 98.137.200.255...
*   Trying 2001:4998:58:2201::1010...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4998:58:2201::1010: No route to host
*   Trying 2001:4998:58:2201::1010...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4998:58:2201::1010: No route to host
*   Trying 2001:4998:58:2201::1010...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4998:58:2201::1010: No route to host
*   Trying 2001:4998:58:2201::1010...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4998:58:2201::1010: No route to host
```

My ifconfig:

```
$ ifconfig en1
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether b0:34:95:f0:2c:46
        inet 192.168.0.13 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

I'm using Yosemite 10.10.2

Any idea of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example curl tried to connect over IPv4 first and only starts trying IPv6 when that fails. I agree that in your case that isn't very useful (you really should find am ISP that offers IPv6) but I wouldn't consider it a problem either as it has already tried IPv4.

Comment: You are right, it was something related to my use of a VPN connection. When I killed the VPN it started to work again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can ask curl to use IPv4 explicitly:

> curl -4 -v 'http://query.yahooapis.com/'